# Variable is defined in the function but needs re-defining

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using a [JQuery mobile plugin](https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js/blob/master/jqm.autoComplete-1.4.3.js) and having strange problems with it.

If I use it like below, it works.

```
    $("#mainPage").on("pageshow", function(e) {

        var availableTags = ['some', 'about', 'tags'];

        $("#searchField").autocomplete({
            target: $('#suggestions'),
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
```

However if use it like below, it does not work. 
But `cached` is defined in the function and correctly shows the id. 
If I redefine `cached` in the function it works again. Can anyone explain why?

```
    var cached = $("#searchField");

    $("#mainPage").on("pageshow", function(e) {

        var availableTags = ['some', 'about', 'tags'];

        //Alert says searchField
        alert(cached.attr('id'));

        //If I uncomment below line it works.
        //cached = $("#searchField");

        cached.autocomplete({
            target: $('#suggestions'),
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you are using jQuery Mobile. jQuery Mobile does some odd things with pages the way it navigates. Most likely your search field is being removed at some point by jQuery Mobile's navigation. Another posibility is you actually have duplicate ID's, also due to the way jQuery mobile handles page navigation.

Comment: Without more context we won't be able to help very much. I suggest putting together a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: Question is why do you want to declare it outside at all?

Comment: @Rannan to avoid looking it up all the time? The name of the variable *is* `cached`

Comment: @JuanMendes Yeah, That one I should have figured my self ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/9uxtT/
How is it different from your situation ?

Comment: +1 Nice, get the jsfiddle started so the OP can get that reduction going.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same error, unfortunately. There are lots of scripts and I cannot put them there all. I can't solve it neither. I mark this as answer. My quick work around is uncommenting `cached = $("#searchField");` Also `cached = cached ||  $("#searchField");` didn't help because cached is already defined I think.

Answer (score 2):

It's a timing issue in the first version you are searching for the tag "#searchField" after pageshow when all jquery modules have been loaded and DOM is complete

In the second version you are searching for the tag whenever the javascript is loaded which might sometimes not even find the #searchfield if the javascript is in the header of the same file.

To complete the answer:
Need to take in consideration that JQuery selectors return Objects and not DOM Elements check this code to see that you get two different objects:

```
 var cached = $("#searchField");
 cached.test = 1;
 $("#p2").on("pageshow", function(e) {
     var test2 = $("#searchField");
 test2.test =2; alert(cached.test +"!="+ test2.test);
 });​
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this. If the `searchField` doesn't exist than the reference to it stored in `cached` would be `[]` and the alert would show `undefined`. The alert using `cached.attr('id')` shows the id though. Hence the element was found originally. As `cached` is only a reference to the DOM element the reference looks like it is still in tact otherwise the alert would not find the id attribute. Or am I missing something?

Comment: OK, I think it might have to do with prototyping, are you loading the autocomplete javascript after this javascript is called?

Comment: ok, that explains why you don't get "undefined" you are calling it after the element is in DOM, but before JQueryMobile had a chance to enhance it's functionality with plugins.

Comment: Need to take in consideration that JQuery selectors return Objects and not DOM Elements check this code to see that you get two different objects:

var cached = $("#searchField");
cached.test = 1;
$("#p2").on("pageshow", function(e) {
        var availableTags = ['some', 'about', 'tags'];
var test2 = $("#searchField");
    test2.test =2;
    alert(cached.test +"!="+ test2.test);
});​

Comment: Thanks I will look back to it.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#searchField")` is not defined when you are calling it outside the function, here's the simple way to cache it the first time the handler is called

```
var cached;

$("#mainPage").on("pageshow", function(e) {
    // This line will only call jQuery once
    cached = cached ||  $("#searchField");

    var availableTags = ['some', 'about', 'tags'];

    alert(cached.attr('id'));

    cached.autocomplete({
        target: $('#suggestions'),
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Here's how to do it without a global variable, by using a self calling function to wrap that variable in a closure

```
$("#mainPage").on("pageshow", (function(){
    var cached;
    return function(e) {
        // This line will only call jQuery once
        cached = cached ||  $("#searchField");

        var availableTags = ['some', 'about', 'tags'];

        alert(cached.attr('id'));

        cached.autocomplete({
            target: $('#suggestions'),
            source: availableTags
        });
    }
})());
```

Comment: Same question: How does `alert(cached.attr('id'));` show the value and not `undefined` in the original code if `searchField` would not have existed?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I don't understand that, can you create a reduction in http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I'm only reading the oringal code of OP in which it says in the second code sample above the alert `//Alert says searchField`, indicating the element exists. OP also states `But cached is defined in the function and correctly shows the id.` This would not be possible if `searchField` would no have existed at all before `pageShow` was triggered as otherwise `alert(cached.attr('id'));` would show `undefined`;

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I do understand what you are saying, I don't understand why that's happening. That's why I said you should create a reduction at http://jsfiddle.net If you're not willing to do that, I would look into the difference between the two object before and after you reset it within the handler

Comment: I wouldn't know how to replicate this in a fiddle. I think OP should be able to do it, seeing it is in the OP's statement that the id was shown.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Sorry, I thought you were the OP :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion :) I thought the same as you and `Raanan` but then wondered why would the id alert out if that would be the case, so I wasn;t able to come up with an answer. `Maciej` did a fiddle though now. nice :)

Comment: +1 I cannot reproduce the same error, unfortunately. There are lots of scripts and I cannot put them there all. I can't solve it neither. My quick work around is uncommenting `cached = $("#searchField");` Also `cached = cached ||  $("#searchField");` didn't help because cached is already defined I think.